# kubernetes -I changed the deployment name ,then redeploying to the environment,how to cleanup the old deployment and pods with old name?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

Had requirement to change the pod or deployment name.now when we deploy,we have 2 deployments and 3 pods each with old and new name 
So far i was deleting the old deployments manually.

do i need to manually delete the old deployment and pods or is there a better method?

Comment: Yeah, you need to delete the previous one manually. Object names in Kubernetes are immutable, so you can't rename them.

Comment: Why don't you just keep the same name and apply the changes to the existing deployment? `$ kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`

Comment: just delete old deployment by its name. It will delete underneath old pods. kubectl delete deploy old-deploy-name.

Answer (score 0):

To delete deployment use

```
$ kubectl delete deploy/old_deployment_name
```

This will delete deployment, including pods and rs, if you  had them.

And dont do this mistake the second time :) @Kamol is right - the best way of managing resources is change config file(e.g your deployment) and re-apply with

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can also remove everything if its installed with the `apply` command

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

you can delete

```
kubectl delete -f deployment.yaml
```